# Solr phrase query with stop word

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I'm sending the request to the Solr that contains a stop word in it.
The Solr version is 5.3.

The query is, where 'the' is stop word:

```
q:{!complexphrase}(my_field_text:"the test")
```

As a result, Solr/Lucene throws an exception:

```
null:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Less than 2 subSpans.size():1
at org.apache.lucene.search.spans.ConjunctionSpans.<init>(ConjunctionSpans.java:38)
at org.apache.lucene.search.spans.NearSpans.<init>(NearSpans.java:30)
at org.apache.lucene.search.spans.NearSpansOrdered.<init>(NearSpansOrdered.java:52)
at org.apache.lucene.search.spans.SpanNearQuery$SpanNearWeight.getSpans(SpanNearQuery.java:232)
at org.apache.lucene.search.spans.SpanWeight.scorer(SpanWeight.java:144)
at org.apache.lucene.search.Weight.bulkScorer(Weight.java:135)
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:769)
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:486)
at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.buildAndRunCollectorChain(SolrIndexSearcher.java:200)
at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListNC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1682)
at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1501)
at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.search(SolrIndexSearcher.java:555)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.process(QueryComponent.java:522)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:277)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2068)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:669)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:462)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:210)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:179)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I believe the issue happens because `the` is removed, and only `test` is left.
Changing query to seems working fine, but I'm not sure it's a correct fix for the issue:

```
q:{!complexphrase}(my_field_text:"the+test")
```

What I want to have as a result is search for full phrase `the test` or at least for `test` if first case is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was because of {!complexphrase}.
It's required to escape special symbols twice in case of using this parser.
So "the test" should be:

```
"the\\\ test"
```

After the first escape, it will be "the\ test". After second - "the\\ test".

Comment: This problem got me too, albeit in a slightly different context. If you also need to specify non-`complexphrase` clauses in your query and use the nested `_query_:"..."` syntax for that purpose, all escape sequences will need to be re-escaped YET AGAIN. So the above then becomes `the\\\\ test`.